# Divergent sequence with only one accumulation point

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to  find some examples of divergent sequences that have a unique accumulation point (in the context of $R^n$, with the usual topology). I know that if a sequence converges, then it has a unique accumulation point, but the inverse sentence is not true. I found one using $n$ and $1/n$, but I can't find another example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence $f(n) = 1$ for odd $n$ and $f(n) = n $ for even $n$.

Comment: Great example! If $A = R (\{ \hat{x}_k \})$ and $|A'| = 1$, then $\hat{x}_k$ converges or $\hat{x}_{k_l}$, for some subsequence, converges to the unique element of $A'$. Isn't it true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any convergent sequence, and let $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any divergent sequence with no accumulation point. (For instance, $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ could be any monotonic sequence diverging to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.) For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $c_{2n}=a_n$ and $c_{2n+1}=b_n$, so that

$$\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots\rangle\,;$$

then $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ diverges and has exactly one accumulation point, namely, the limit of the convergent sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.